# How to programmatically cut and paste Vue component with all data and methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have zone that contain a lot of elements. 
**This elements generated with Vue.compile( ) and creating new instance:**

```
const instance = Vue.extend(resizableBox);
let completeElem = new instance (
        {
          propsData: {
            ...
          },
          parent: this,
          store
        }
    );

    let compiledHTML = Vue.compile(this.html); // some html string

    completeElem.$slots.innerNode = [completeElem.$createElement(compiledHTML)];
    completeElem.$mount('.replaceMe');
```

**Generated HTML:**

```
<div class="zone">
    <div class="resizer" style="left: 0px; top: 20px">
        <div class="handlers">...</div>
        <div class="textNode">
            <span>IT'S TEXT</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to cut generated node with all methods and data in. And then paste it in different place.
I can't use render func, because all my elements are movable (in zone bounds) and i can spawn new from list (with drag&drop api). 
I can't recreate new instance for every move, because i need writed data

Comment: "because i need writed data" - what does this means? "I need to cut generated node with all methods and data in" - this doesn't make sense from tech point of view. You could possibly attach DOM element to different parent. But generally this sounds like XY problem that could be solved in a more reasonable way.

Comment: @Estus Flask
1) writed data => data( ) {...
2) How i can change place of element in DOM with saving vue data? (For example, append it to different zone. clone method from DOM does not copy `__vue__` part)
3) Now i'm just moving element with xy change, but what if some element will be changed somehow different with distance traveled? That's why i need cut and paste